# Escaping apostrophe in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql-9.1

I am trying to escape a single quote in a ruby string. I am using this string as a insert query to push data into the postgresql.

The query that will be generated looks something like this:-

```
str = insert into table field1,field2 values 'Gaurav's', 'Scooter'
```

I tried escaping it with

```
str.gsub("/'/",\\\\')
```

But this didn't work.

The error that I always get is:
**Syntax Error Near s:**

I guess i would need a regex to escape single quote inside the two single quotes not sure though.

How do I fix this? Thank you.

Comment: Are you using the ruby-pg gem?

Comment: yes i am using the ruby pg gem

Comment: Also, shouldn't your string be double quoted?  `str = "insert...`

Comment: Yeah the string is double qouted. I am sorry forgot to add that. But I can only use this if I know what values I want to insert . If I have the values in a single string variable like fieldStr = "field1,field2" and valuesStr = "Gaurav's, Scooter". Then How Do i Go about it?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your comment above.  Are you saying that you are given a SQL string?  Or that you know the values to insert?

Comment: Then your question changes a bit.

Comment: Ok , I am saying that I don't know the values that are to be inserted as in what are fields and values inserted are not known to me. So I have these values in a two different string variables and hence my insert query looks like insertScriptStr =  "insert into " + objectName + "(" + headerStr + ") values (" + fieldStr + ")" where the objectName are the fields and the fieldStr are the values

Comment: Ok, check out my answer.  Modify your question to reflect this discussion.

Answer (score 2):

You should used [prepared statements](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement).  Prepared statements help increase your speed.  The query is parsed once by the DB.  They also help you avoid having to do manual escaping as you are trying to do.

```
f1_val = "Gaurav's"
f2_val = "Scooter"

# conn is your connection object
conn.prepare('givethisqueryaname', "INSERT INTO table field1,field2 VALUES ($1,$2)")
conn.exec_prepared('givethisqueryaname',[f1_val, f2_val])
```

If you are given the field names, and field values as a string, then you can do this.

```
fieldStr = "field1,field2"
valuesStr = "Gaurav's, Scooter"
arr = valuesStr.split(",")
conn.prepare('insert_x', "INSERT INTO table #{fieldStr} VALUES ($1,$2)")
conn.exec_prepared('insert_x', arr)
```

Answer (score 0):

This works if the single quote you want to escape always is in front of a "s"

```
1.9.3p125 :020 > str = "insert into table field1,field2 values 'Gaurav's', 'Scooter'"
 => "insert into table field1,field2 values 'Gaurav's', 'Scooter'" 
1.9.3p125 :021 > str.gsub("'s","-s")
 => "insert into table field1,field2 values 'Gaurav-s', 'Scooter'"
```

You can user the  difference between single quotes(') and double quotes(").